# Stacked bar plot in R with multiple rows per day

Tags: r, charts, plot, data-visualization, bar-chart

I would like to display work done in a day as a stacked bar plot, in order to see, day by day, how much activity I've done in each category, with the Y-axis representing time from 0:00 to 23:59.

```
#   day             tstart   tend   duration category
1   2012-10-01      13:40    14:16  36       Recreation
2   2012-10-02      10:15    10:57  42       Work
3   2012-10-02      13:23    13:47  24       Chores
4   2012-10-02      13:47    14:48  61       Work
5   2012-10-03      09:09    11:40  151      Work
6   2012-10-03      13:33    14:04  31       Recreation
7   2012-10-03      17:00    19:40  160      Recreation
```

I know I will have to convert "time start" as a numeric, but I don't know how to "merge" the multiple rows for the same day, so that they're making up only one bar in the plot.

In (very primitive) ASCII art, what I'm expecting is something like:

```
23:00
22:00
21:00
20:00
19:00                C
18:00                C
17:00                C
16:00
15:00
14:00          W     R
13:00    R     C
12:00
11:00                W
10:00          W     W
 9:00                W
 8:00
 7:00
 6:00
 5:00
 4:00
 3:00
 2:00
 1:00
 0:00
        01    02    03
```

(where R, W and C would be bars of different colors for the different activites: Recreation, Work and Chores)

In fact, being newbie in R plots, I don't know the plot function (and the plot package) I have to look at, moreover as they're will be holes in the plot -- no activity recorded (for example) between 0:00 and 09:09, then between 11:40 and 13:33, etc. on 2012-10-03...

Comment: Are you looking for sort of a [Gantt chart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gantt_chart)?

Comment: No. The idea, here, is to get a chart where we see -- day per day -- how much time (from 13:40, for 36 minutes, etc.) we work on which activity. It's based on "clocked" time (recorded activity).

Comment: OTOH, a Gantt chart's unit is tasks, and sub-tasks. There is a notion of decomposition, which we don't have here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a quick solution with `ggplot2` :

```
d <- read.table(textConnection("
day             tstart   tend   duration category
2012-10-01      13:40    14:16  36       Recreation
2012-10-02      10:15    10:57  42       Work
2012-10-02      13:23    13:47  24       Chores
2012-10-02      13:47    14:48  61       Work
2012-10-03      09:09    11:40  151      Work
2012-10-03      13:33    14:04  31       Recreation
2012-10-03      17:00    19:40  160      Recreation"), header=TRUE)

d$day <- as.Date(d$day)
d$tstart <- as.POSIXct(d$tstart, format="%H:%M")
d$tend <- as.POSIXct(d$tend, format="%H:%M")

library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
g <- ggplot(data=d, aes()) + geom_segment(aes(x=day,xend=day,y=tstart,yend=tend,color=category),size=20) + scale_x_date(labels = date_format("%d")) 
g + scale_y_datetime(limits=c(as.POSIXct("00:00", format="%H:%M"),as.POSIXct("23:59", format="%H:%M")), labels = date_format("%H:%M"))
```

Which gives :

[image]

**EDITED :** the y axis in the initial answer was wrong.

Comment: (+1) Maybe you should include the range 00:00 to 23:59 to complete the answer?

Comment: +1 on the above comment, which is a nice-to-have (with the resolution of the clock -- for example: increments of 0:15 for legend of the Y-axis).

Comment: For the rest, this is a wonderful answer, opening me to a new world of possibilities (ggplot2, which I did not know)

Comment: In fact it is not a wonderful answer, because the y-axis is all wrong... Arun made me realised that, I'am in the way for a solution...

Comment: Wait; there is a little "feature", though: the ticks of the Y-axis are not correctly spaced, according to the real time. Is that possible?

Comment: Ok, I've just edited my answer. Now the y axis is correct, and I added the range from 00:00 to 23:59. Sorry for the initial mistake !

Answer (score 4):

While I was writing this post, juba posted excellent solution using ggplot2, I will post my solution nonetheless as an alternative.

This is very crude way of doing it, but it accomplishes what you may be looking for.

First a small utility function to convert time of format `hh:mm` to decimal representation

```
decTime <- function(x) {
    t <- as.numeric(strsplit(x, ":")[[1]])
    t <- t[1] + t[2]/60
    return(t)
}

str <- 'n   day     tstart   tend   duration category
1   2012-10-01      13:40    14:16  36       Recreation
2   2012-10-02      10:15    10:57  42       Work
3   2012-10-02      13:23    13:47  24       Chores
4   2012-10-02      13:47    14:48  61       Work
5   2012-10-03      09:09    11:40  151      Work
6   2012-10-03      13:33    14:04  31       Recreation
7   2012-10-03      17:00    19:40  160      Recreation'

df <- read.table(textConnection(str), header=T)
```

Convert day to numeric (for ease of specifying width of rectangles) and times to decimal

```
df$day  <- gsub('2012-10-', "", df$day)
df$day <- as.numeric(df$day)
df$starttime <- sapply(as.character(df$tstart), decTime, USE.NAMES=F)
df$endtime <- sapply(as.character(df$tend), decTime, USE.NAMES=F)
```

Get colors for different rectangles

```
df$color <- ifelse(df$category=='Recreation', 'RED', ifelse(df$category =='Chores', 'BLUE', 'GREEN'))
```

Plot the graph one step at at time

```
#Plot empty graph
plot(x=unique(df$day), y=c(0,0,0), axes=F, ylim=c(0,24), xlim=c(0.5,3.5), xlab='date', ylab='time', type='n')
#Label axes properly
axis(side=1, at=c(1,2,3), labels=c('01', '02', '03'))
axis(side=2, at=seq(from=0,to=24,by=1), labels=seq(from=0,to=24,by=1))
#Draw required rectangles
rect(df$day-0.25, df$starttime, df$day+0.25, df$endtime, col=df$color)
```

Result should be somewhat you may want.

[image]

Comment: Nice to have a solution with base graphics !

Comment: Very nice solution as well. Exactly what I asked for, ans so quickly... Thanks a lot!